# Finding if a value is located in a range of cells in a corresponding column, to a row with the same value as a given cell in a given row

Tags: excel

Given that column A contains directory paths, and column B contains actions on these paths; I'd like a resultant cell to contain a specific string if a specific string is located in Column B (per column A).

Granted I can sort the column, I believe I can use `OFFSET`, but would like to know how to locate an ending index of cells so I can search the `range` returned by `OFFSET`.

For example:

```
Path                Operation
/share/Admins       Accessed
/share/Admins       Removed
/share/Admins       Added
/share/Admins       Changed
/share/Network      Accessed
/shared/Projects    Accessed
```

In this case, I want to search `Path` for a unique value (in this case `/share/Admins`, `/share/Network`, and `/shared/Projects`), and given this range in `Path`, I'd like to search the corresponding `Operation`, and if any Operation that matches `Removed`, `Added`, `Changed` exists, I'd like the cell value to be `WRITE`; and if those values aren't found, "READ".

In this case, I would expect the column (with header `Result`) to read:

```
Path                Operation       Result
/share/Admins       Accessed        WRITE
/share/Admins       Removed         WRITE
/share/Admins       Added           WRITE
/share/Admins       Changed         WRITE
/share/Network      Accessed        READ
/shared/Projects    Accessed        READ
```

Pardon the SEO:  I am using this to compare Varonis DatAdvantage reports `01.a.01` (user access logs) with `04.j.01` (effective user permissions report).  Unfortunately, DatAdvantage doesn't feel the need to write reports that correlate their user activity records and file system permissions records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sumproduct. See screenshot.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A:A=A1)*((B:B="Removed")+(B:B="Added")+(B:B="Changed"))),"WRITE","READ")
```

[image]

Or in shorter form:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A:A=A1)*(B:B={"Removed","Added","Changed"})),"WRITE","READ")
```

Comment: Perfect!  Quick question: Is it possible to explicitly place a condition when the value will be "READ" as well as "WRITE" instead of the catchall of "READ" when not....?  Is this possible to do with three fields?

Comment: Yes, it's just another IF statement within the first. What would the condition be?

Comment: Right now, this is great!  I'll mess around more if and when I really need these things.  Thank you much!